# Java generics, interfaces and type constraints

Tags: java, generics, interface

given a generic interface:

```
public interface I<E> {
    public int interfaceMethod(E s);
}
```

and a generic class that implements the interface

```
public class A<T> implements I<T> {

    private T val;

    public A(T x) {
        val = x;
    }

    public int interfaceMethod(T val) {
        // looks like T should be of the same type as instance variable 'val'
        return 0;
    }

}
```

why does the following work?

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A<String>("hello");

        System.out.println(a.interfaceMethod(100)); \\ returns 0
    }
}
```

I expected the `T` type parameter of the method `interfaceMethod` as defined in `class A` to constrain the method to arguments that have the same type as that supplied to the constructor of `A`. (in this case `String`).

Why does `a.interfaceMethod` not require an argument of type `String`?

Comment: probably because I didn't do the following `A<String> a = new A<String>("hello");`...

Comment: I would venture that the integer is implicitly cast to String http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159358/implicit-cast-to-string-tostring-and-int

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers explained that a compiler warning should normally show up. The explanation I was looking for came in the form of the [link to a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) provided by @JB Nizet.

`T t = new T<S>()`

is not the same as

`T<S> t = new T<S>()`

The first is an example of a **raw type**.
I was interested in **why** this works (i.e... if it compiles and does not throw a run-time error) then there must be something to it.

The answers of that post are detailed and explain exactly why this compiles (long story short, backwards compatibility). The post goes into full detail and explains the implications for Java's type system.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you ignored the warning "Raw use of parameter a" (or something like that)

Use:

```
A<String> a = new A<String>("hello");
```

When ignoring generic related warnings the code may compile when shouldn't.

Comment: There were no warnings... Or are these java-docs warnings?

Comment: If you use intellij/eclipse you should see the warnings unless they are disabled.

Comment: It definitely issues a warning: *Run.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.*

Comment: using intellij - ok - only see that I have a compiler warning when i select : Analyze - Inspect Code...

Answer (score 1):

This works because `a` instance is typed to `A` class only
You should type it like this:

```
A<String> a = new A<String>("hello");
```

If you wont specify the parameter, you will be able to put there all data types like `String`, `int` etc.

Comment: You are right, @JBNizet, removed

Comment: Sorry, saw it and improved right now @JBNizet